# How to copy this portion of the array to a new array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have this php array X.

```
X= array(
    'Parent' => array(
        'title' => '123',
    )
)
```

I have this php array Y.

```
Y = array(
    'Parent' => array(
        'id' => '16',
        'title' => 'T1',
    ),
    'Children' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '8',
            'serial_no' => '1',
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '9',
            'serial_no' => '2',
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'id' => '14',
            'serial_no' => '6',
        )
    )
)
```

I want to copy the Children of array Y to the parent of array X to form array Z such that it looks like this;

```
Z= array(
        'Parent' => array(
            'title' => '123',
        )
        'Children' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(                   
                'serial_no' => '1'
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'serial_no' => '2'
            ),
            (int) 2 => array(
                'serial_no' => '6'
            )
        )
    )
```

Please note that the id key-value pair was removed from the Children of array Y.

I wrote some code of my own.

```
            $Z = array();
            $i=0;
            foreach($Y as $temp) 
            {
                $Z['Children'][$i] = $temp['Children'][$i];     
                unset($Z['Children'][$i]['id'];
                $i++;
            }    
            $Z['Parent']=$temp['Parent'];
```

Unfortunately, there is an undefined index error. How can this be done in php? Forget about my code if there are better approaches.

Comment: but id key is removed only at one element. rest of places its present

Comment: Wow! You are very sharp!! I have corrected the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your approach works too, but you need to iterate over sub-array:

```
$Z = array();
$i=0;
foreach($Y['Children'] as $temp) 
{
    $Z['Children'][$i] = $temp;     
    unset($Z['Children'][$i]['id'];
    $i++;
}
```

or what I may do:

```
$Z = $X;
$Z['Children'] = array();
foreach ( $Y['Children'] as $child ) {
    $Z['Children'][] = array(
        'serial_no' => $child['serial_no'],
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like.

```
   $Z = array();
   foreach($Y['Children'] as $temp) 
   {
      $Z['Children'][] = array('serial_no' => $temp['serial_no']);     
   }    
   $Z['Parent']=$X['Parent'];
```

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. But I can only choose one as the right answer. I gave credit to the other answer which corrected my code.